# Making persistant for Toggle Columns in treetable

Tags: primeng, primeng-treetable

Is there any example you have to make the table data persistent after hide or show or reorder certain columns in primeng.

For example:
If there is a treetable with 3 columns Id,Name and type and by toggling I hided the ID column using toggle option and if I refreshed the page, the table should come with Name and type only.

Is there any api is available to get the column data dynamically for each hide and show as well as reordering ? kindly provide an example it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an API for this.. I used localstorage for saving the state of the table.

Comment: local storage and session storage are all dependent on browser but I want to achieve the same sate across different browser